# How to apply css filter in mozilla?

Tags: css, mozilla

> filter:
>   progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=1,opacity=80
>   );
>                                                                           opacity: 0.5; -moz-opacity: 0.5

This works well with IE but I want this to work in mozilla also. What is the solution?

Comment: I got the answer background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left,black,white)

Comment: @Poomina that is in no way relevant to the code you posted

Comment: I need to apply filtering and style for an element and instead of giving filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=1,opacity=80 ); we can give like background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left,black,white) for mozilla. mozilla does not support filter as far as i heard. -moz-opacity can be given but for giving gradient effects and all we need to apply the above said style

Answer (score 1):

These are three definitions that do the same thing:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=1,opacity=80 ); // IE only
opacity: 0.5; // CSS 2, FireFox supports this from version 3
-moz-opacity: 0.5 // FireFox only, pre 3.x versions
```

See [opacity on QuirksMode](http://quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html), [CSS compatibility on QuirksMode](http://quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t411)

So, it does work in Mozilla FireFox in versions 3.x and higher.

Comment: I got the answer background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left,black,white)

Answer (score 0):

`opacity:0.5` should be working in mozilla, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/opacity

Have you ran firebug or anything to see if the another style is being applied?

Comment: I got the answer. background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left,black,white)